# Whats the errors not able to understand

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, pointers, typedef

i made a code but has errors and wan't able to solve them:-

the following errors are in one of mine header file(code shown below)

> error C2143:syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Header file code:-

```
#ifndef _DEVICE_SOURCE_FICARD_HH
#define _DEVICE_SOURCE_FICARD_HH

#ifndef _FRAMED_SOURCE_HH
#include "FramedSource.hh"
#endif

#include <DeviceSource.hh>

typedef struct LtagBufferEntry
{
  char *pBuffer;
  struct LtagBufferEntry *pNext;
} LBufferEntry;

class FICardDeviceParameters {
public:
    (RetEntry*)(*p_lm_lock_fn)( void *data );  //error at this line
    void (*p_lm_unlock_fn)( void *data );
    int nFICardFrameSize;
  //%%% TO BE WRITTEN %%%
};

class DeviceSourceFICard: public DeviceSource {
public:
  static DeviceSourceFICard* createNew(UsageEnvironment& env, FICardDeviceParameters fi_params,
                 DeviceParameters params);

protected:
  DeviceSourceFICard(UsageEnvironment& env, FICardDeviceParameters fi_params, DeviceParameters params);
  // called only by createNew(), or by subclass constructors
  virtual ~DeviceSourceFICard();

private:
  // redefined virtual functions:
  virtual void doGetNextFrame();

private:
  void deliverFrame();

private:
  DeviceParameters fParams;
  LBufferEntry *pData;
  char         * pRetData;
  //int nFICardFrameSize;
  FICardDeviceParameters fiParams;
};

#endif //_DEVICE_SOURCE_FICARD_HH
```

Defination of RetEntry:-

```
typedef struct tagRetBuffer
{
  char *pBuffer;
  int nDataLn;
} RetEntry;

void InitBufferHandling();
void TransferBuffer( void *pBuffer );
RetEntry *lm_lock_fn( void *data );
void lm_unlock_fn( void *data );
int initLm555Settings(void);
void play();
void afterPlaying(void*);
void init_play();
void StartRTPProcess(void);
```

How to fix them...

Comment: I assume it tells you about a specifc line which this error relates to ?

Comment: I guess `RetEntry` is undefined at the point of the error. Is an #include missing?

Comment: Line numbers would help, but this "C++ does not support default-int" gives you a good idea what you are looking for!

Comment: Wow, this is hideous C++ code.

Comment: all the three errors mentioned above i am getting in line(in the code):- (RetEntry*)(*p_lm_lock_fn)( void *data );

Comment: @Harry: this is C code with classes, is `RetEntry` supposed to be shared with C code or not ? If not, define it as `struct RetEntry { .... };` instead of introducing a tag and then using `typedef`, then you can use Naveen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler does not know what `RetEntry` is in the expression:

```
(RetEntry*)(*p_lm_lock_fn)( void *data );
```

You must either include the header that provides the definition or else declare it in your current header. From the code below it seems to be a typedef to `tagRetBuffer`, so to *declare* it in the current translation unit you will need to declare the struct and the typedef:

```
struct tagRetBuffer;
typedef tagRetBuffer RetEntry;
```

Now, I would suggest that you avoid those typedef's altogether, in C++ the compiler will search for types if needed. You can just do:

```
struct RetEntry
{
  char *pBuffer;
  int nDataLn;
};
```

And then use `RetEntry` anywhere as if it was a typedef'ed name. Note that there are differences, but that in 99% of the cases you will not notice. And when you do notice it might even be to your advantage (for example, you cannot *declare* a typedef, so you need to *declare* the typedef'ed name and then redefine the typedef as per the first suggestion here).

Comment: i included the header where RetEntry was defined now i am getting the error:-error C2011: 'tagRetBuffer' : 'struct' type redefinition

Comment: @Harry, that means that you are redefining the struct in your translation unit. Are you including that header multiple times? Does the header have include guards? (Equivalent code to trigger the same error: `struct X {}; struct X {};` --note both *define* the struct even if they define it to be the same, that is not allowed.